# highcharts mouse over/out events fired in wrong timing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart with mouse over and out events on series.point.events, where I need to use the current hovered column category. 
The over event is fired when entering the column area, but when hovering the column itself, the out event is fired. Is this behavior correct? Am I using the events the wrong way?

here are the chart options:

```
  var options = {
chart: {
  type: 'column'
},

xAxis: {
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
    'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
  ]
},

tooltip: {
  shared: true,
  crosshairs: true
},

series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
  point: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $mouseState.html("mouse state OVER: " + this.category);
        }, 2000);
      },
      mouseOut: function() {
        $mouseState.html("mouse state OUT: " + this.category);
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

};

*** the timeout is only only for debugging

http://jsfiddle.net/62yhg2hq/3/

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the events to go under **plotOptions**

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function(event) {
                        $mouseState.html("mouse state OVER: " +  this.category);
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        $mouseState.html("mouse state OUT: " + this.category);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Updated fiddle with removed **shared:true** tooltip:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62yhg2hq/8/)

Comment: thanks, but i still have the same problem. when hovering a column area, without touching the column itself, the events are fired, but the wrong category is printed.

Comment: remove shared tooltip - **shared: true**, you have only 1 data set, so nothing to share

Comment: this helps with the events, so thank you! but is there a way to show the hover background when entering a column area without touching it? the column might not be visible because it's value is 0, but i still need to be able to hover it.

Comment: @NinaMordakhay Behavior of Highcharts is like that by design, but if you want to have xAxis' crosshair visible without the events, then you could use a wrapper in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2rh6ta8d/

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you remove setTimeout, it will work fine. You are seeing firing 'mouseover event' after 2sec.

Please make stickyTracking=false, Because if true, mouseOut event on a series isn't triggered until the mouse moves over another series.
[http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.stickyTracking]

And make tooltip.shared=false ,Because tooltip will be hidden when moving the mouse between series.

```
$(function() {
var i=0;
var j=0;
var $mouseState = $('#mouseState');
var $mouseState2 = $('#mouseState2');
var options = {
chart: {
  type: 'column'
},

xAxis: {
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
    'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
  ]
},

tooltip: {
  shared: false,
  crosshairs: true
},

series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
  stickyTracking: false,
  point: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function(event) {

          $mouseState.html("mouse state OVER: " + this.category +" Number "+i++);

      },
      mouseOut: function() {
     $mouseState2.html("mouse state OUT: " + this.category +" Number "+ j++); 
      }
    }
  }
  }]
};

$('#container').highcharts(options);
});
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/62yhg2hq/9/]

Comment: thanks, but I used the timeout only for debugging. In your example, when you hover a column area, without touching the column itself, the events are fired, but the wrong category is printed.